# Support for rel="author"?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Link Stack Overflow profile pages to Google profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103335/link-stack-overflow-profile-pages-to-google-profile)

You may or may not have heard about the new [rel="author" tag](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=1408986) that some sites (most notably Google) are using to identify authorship of online content. It's still very new, so there's still only a few benefits it brings, but the main one has to be the extra information provided on Google search results:

[image: Google search result with rel=author]

In order for this magic to happen, basically three things need to be present:

1. A link from the "content page" to the "author page" which contains the rel="author" parameter.
2. A link from the "author page" to a Google profile which also contains the &rel=author query parameter.
3. A link on the Google profile back to the website hosting those pages.

Steps 2 and 3 are already under the control of any Stack Exchange user -- however, **Stack Overflow has to decide if it wants to take Step 1**. Consider the benefits of adding the rel="author" parameter to, say, the accepted answer of a question, if the answerer has over 2,000 reputation. It would certainly incentivize having accepted answers (over votes) even more. I can also see people being more vigilant with keeping an answer up-to-date if their name is on the search result. Not to mention, search results with authors pop out more on the Google results page, and I wouldn't be surprised if (now or in the future) those results get some extra Google Juice of their own.

On the other hand, if someone does ***not*** want to have their name associated this way, it's incredibly easy to do: just *don't* include a link to Stack Overflow on your Google profile, or a link to your Google profile on your SO author page. **It's explicitly opt-in and nearly impossible to achieve by accident**, so there's no privacy concerns.

Since SO still sees Google as its primary interface, I think it would be a great idea to take advantage of one of Google's more ambitious new efforts, and showcase great answer-ers even more.

Discuss, and remember -- Jon Skeet is almost certainly going to be in favor of this ;)